# convergence uniform of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E=\mathcal{C}[0,1]$. How to prove that if $f_n\rightarrow f$ with the norm $\displaystyle{\|\cdot\|_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0, 1]}f(t)}$ then  $f_n\rightarrow f$ with the norm $\displaystyle{\|\cdot\|_p=\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|^p\,dt\right)^{1/p}}$.

Give an example showing that the converse is not true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start for the first part
$$ \displaystyle{\|f_n-f\|^p_p= \int_{0}^{1}|f_n(t)-f(t)|^p\,dt }\leq   \int_{0}^{1}\sup|f_n(t)-f(t)|^p\,dt \leq \dots. $$

Comment: Mhenni know an example for the second part?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: Check the sequence $x^n$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: Check the the convergence in the two norms $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$ and $\|\cdot \|_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: If $|f-g|<\epsilon$, what can you say about $\|f-g\|_p$?

Draw the graph of a continuous function $f$ with $\|f\|_1<\epsilon$ and $\|f\|_\infty=1$.